# SQL - Cross Join when Left Join isn't met

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, cartesian-product, cross-join

I am unsure if this is even the correct way to do this but I'll explain the situation.

I have two tables, the first table is a list of products while the second is a list of channels. I want to do a LEFT JOIN if the join condition is met else I want to explode the rows for every channel in the CHANNEL table. I've read about CROSS JOINs but not sure if that is the way to go.

`SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, C.CHANNEL, C.REGION, C.COUNTRY, C.LANGUAGE
  FROM PRODUCT P
  LEFT JOIN CHANNEL C
    ON C.CHANNEL = P.CHANNEL;`

**Product Table**

```
Product_ID | Product_Name | Channel
------------------------------------
12345678   | Product1     | Ecommerce
87654321   | Product2     | 
14785236   | Product3     | Outlet
```

**Channel Table**

```
CHANNEL   | REGION   | COUNTRY | LANGUAGE
--------------------------------------
Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | EN
Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | FR
Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | EN
Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | FR
[...]
```

I'm expecting this output:

```
PRODUCT_ID | CHANNEL | REGION | COUNTRY | LANGUAGE
---------------------------------------------------
12345678 | Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | EN
12345678 | Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | FR
87654321 | Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | EN
87654321 | Ecommerce | Americas | Canada  | FR
87654321 | Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | EN
87654321 | Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | FR
[...]
14785236 | Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | EN
14785236 | Outlet    | Americas | Canada  | FR
```

I am working in an Oracle DB.

Guidance would very much appreciate for this.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: `else I want to explode the rows for every channel in the CHANNEL table` - what does that mean?

Comment: Can you post a example of data and example of wanted result?

Comment: " if the join condition is met"? Well, I see just two cases: `product.channel is not null` then it is set to a channel I find in the channel table, or `product.channel is null` then it is of course not set to a channel I find in the channel table. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I added a sample output if it helps.

Comment: Ah, so I understood correctly and my answer solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need an inner join where the condition is a channel match (so as to get that one channel joined) or `product.channel is null` (so as to get all channels joined):

```
SELECT p.product_id, c.channel, c.region, c.country, c.language
  FROM product p
  JOIN channel c on c.channel = p.channel OR p.channel IS NULL;
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, the "P.CHANNEL" doesn't look right. A product can only have 1 channel?  Looks like you need a xrefProductsChannels table that just has ProductId and ChannelId in it.

To answer your question, this is how you get all products with all channels:

```
SELECT P.PRODUCT_ID, 
C.CHANNEL, 
C.REGION, 
C.COUNTRY, 
C.LANGUAGE,
CASE WHEN P.channel = C.channel THEN 1 ELSE 0 END HasChannel
FROM PRODUCT P
CROSS JOIN CHANNEL C
```